# Serial monitor window opens frozen

Tags: serial, ide

My serial monitor window opens frozen, without any output or possibility to input, or even activate the window.
Sketch is very simple, but behavior is same even with empty sketch, so I assume problem is not in sketch. I also checked if sketch is uploaded correctly by uploading simple sketch with blinking diode, which worked.

Same behavior with Arduino Nano and Uno.

I tried to reinstall IDE, uninstalled, removed and reinstalled serial driver (ch340) with no success.

I can see Serial monitor window only on windows taskbar, it won't activate after click.

Until now I haven't had any significant problems with IDE or serial monitor for years.

[image: window state]

Comment: Is it uploading at all?

Comment: Yes, sketch is correctly uploaded, I tried to upload another simple sketch with blinking LED, which worked.

Comment: IDE version? Did you get it through the website or the windows store? If you get it from the website, which file did you use?

Comment: I got it from windows store, version is 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0)

Comment: Do you anything plugged in or connected to the Arduino besides the USB cable to the PC?

Comment: No, but I tried it both, with connected MH sensor series flying fish and without on Nano, and with and without 2.4"TFT LCD shield on Uno with same result, meanwhile I tried both arduinos on another PC, where they work normally

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the java. Also check whether the device manager shows the USB serial port without any yellow warning sign on it.
If there is a current short in the usb port that specific port will be off for safety, restarting the computer should resolve that problem.

Comment: Until now I haven't had Java installed, no change in behavior after installation. I restarted computer many times in the process. Driver is correctly installed, and device in device manager is working correctly both with old and new driver.

Comment: The IDE runs on a JVM bundled with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaltely, nothing worked, and after hours of trying and googling I reinstalled windows, and now Serial Monitor works correctly.